# How would you modify the following code to allow for the specified issues to be resolved?

Tags: python, list, class

I have the following code:

```
def __str__() -> str:

     mydict = {a: [1, 2, 3], b: [1, 2]}
     for k, v in mydict.items():
     return f'{k}: {len(v)}'
```

However, the issue with this is, once it reaches the return statement the code stops. However, if I remove the return statement and have:

```
print(f'{k}: {len(v)}')
```

instead, I receive a value error as **str** must return a string.

I was wondering is there a way around this.

Comment: what would be the expected output? Likely a single string, can you use `join`?

Comment: The indentation is wrong. Assuming the return is actually indented correctly then you'll only ever return one value

Comment: @LancelotduLac OP already said that?

Comment: @Nin17 He said, and I quote, "the code stops". Make of that what you will. I certainly don't understand it

Comment: Is there a good reason for defining a function in the style of a dunder method outside the context of a class? If this is a class function then it's missing the instance reference - conventionally *self*

Comment: Please use a less generic title that describes the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind potentially many entries from the dict into a single string to return. You can either do this with string concatenation, inside the loop (start with an empty string, concatenate the new part each iteration, and then once the loop finishes return the string), or you can use `str.join()`, which is usually preferred:

```
def __str__() -> str:

     mydict = {a: [1, 2, 3], b: [1, 2]}
     return '\n'.join(
          f'{k}: {len(v)}' for (k, v) in mydict.items()
     )
```